# No sé como resolver un problema de tkinter y diccionarios

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero mostrar un diccionario en la interfaz de tkinter pero no sé como.

```
import tkinter
dic={1:"pepe",2:"Raul"}
busw=tkinter.Tk()
busw.geometry('420x200')
caja=tkinter.Text(busw,width=38,height=2)
caja.place(x=50,y=90)
buscart=tkinter.Label(busw,text="Buscar por codigo",width=25)
buscart.place(x=30,y=60)
buscadore=tkinter.Entry(busw,text="")
buscadore.place(x=190,y=60)
def buscar(dic): #buscar mediante codigo
    print("Codigo")
    cod=buscadore.get()
    if cod in dic:
        caja.insert(dic[cod][0])
buscarbo=tkinter.Button(busw, text="Buscar",width=20,command=lambda:[buscar(dic)])
buscarbo.place(x=200,y=150)
tkinter.mainloop()
```

**Mi código ** En la consola solo envía código. y no muestra nada en la caja

Comment: para mostrar algo, tu función deberá de retornar un dato, agrega al final de la función `return  caja`

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolvi!

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.constants import END
dic={1:["pepe",28],2:"Raul"}
busw=tkinter.Tk()
busw.geometry('420x200')
caja=tkinter.Text(busw,width=18,height=1)
caja.place(x=40,y=120)
caja2=tkinter.Text(busw,width=18,height=1)
caja2.place(x=200,y=120)
des=tkinter.Label(busw,text="Descripción",width=25)
des.place(x=30,y=100)
can=tkinter.Label(busw,text="Descripción",width=25)
can.place(x=190,y=100)
buscart=tkinter.Label(busw,text="Buscar por codigo",width=25)
buscart.place(x=30,y=20)
buscadore=tkinter.Entry(busw,text="")
buscadore.place(x=190,y=20)
def eliminar():
    caja.delete("0","end")
    caja2.delete("0","end")
def buscar(dic): #buscar mediante codigo
    cod=buscadore.get()
    cod=int(cod)
    if cod in dic.keys():
        caja.insert("1.0",dic[cod][0])
        caja2.insert("1.0",dic[cod][1])
    return  caja
buscarbo=tkinter.Button(busw, text="Buscar",width=20,command=lambda:[buscar(dic),eliminar()])
buscarbo.place(x=190,y=50)
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Pero ahora estoy con otro problema

Comment: Otro problema, otra pregunta